# Сравнение чисел в запросе SQL

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Доброго времени - имеется такой запрос

```
 $tmp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM goodsbra WHERE stems <= '$val'");
```

поле stems - может содержать число от 1 до 100000 без пробелов - а $val тоже произвольно число в таком же диапазоне - так вот в чем вопрос - когда поле stems имеет в таблице тип VARCHAR - то выборка дает какие то не адекватные результаты мне кажется из-за того что сравнивает в строковом порядке - когда даю полю stems тип INT - все работает на ура - хотелось бы узнать - можно ли как то имея у поля тип VARCHAR принудительно заставить через запрос SQL сравнивать параметры как числа?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если надо сравнивать значения как числа, то у поля должен быть тип INT.

Никаких других вариантов в принципе быть не может. Это азбука баз данных.

До некоторого предела БД терпит такие издевательства над собой, но потом становится очень больно. Поэтому надо не искать хитровыдуманные пути обхода изначально неверно спроектированной БД, а делать сразу нормально.

Answer (score -2):

```
 $tmp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM goodsbra WHERE cast(stems as int) <= '$val'");
```

Comment: Судя по phpmyadmin это mysql в нем cast as int не работает. надо писать `as signed`. К этому добавить так же про то, что это приведет к кучу проблем типа неиспользования индексов и сильному падению производительности и токованию любых нечисловых данных как 0,